# Making responsive menu, css doesnt apply on some media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm making responsive menu and I have problems in media query - CSS doesnt apply. You can view it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MPbn3/) . Slide between JavaScript and Result and you can see what is problem... Click on Toggle Menu. Problem is in this query **@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.menu-main, .logo-seperator {
    display:none;
}

.toggle-menu{
    width:100%;
    margin-top:110px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#6c6c6c;
    display:block;
}

 /*DOESNT APPLY*/
.menu_main{
    background:blue;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 20;
}
 /*DOESNT APPLY*/
.menu_main li{
    text-decoration: none !important;
    width:100% !important;
    height:20px !important;
    background-color:black !important;
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It seems to work correctly for me. However, if you start with the smaller layout and you click "toggle menu" to reveal the menu, then you click it again to hide the menu, and finally you expand the screen to the large layout, the menu will be hidden. This is likely because jQuery uses an inline style to hide the menu, which will override the stylesheet rules to display it.

Comment: try to add some css to problematic query and you will see what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is  a typo. In the media query you mentioned, the css selector is using an underscore instead of a dash:

This: `.menu_main`

Should be: `.menu-main`

http://jsfiddle.net/WF7CX/

Also the text-decoration property should be applied to the anchor tag, instead of the list item.